# Print elements of an ArrayList with no repeats

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I have an `ArrayList` of numbers which repeat:

```
1
2
3
1
2
4
```

What I want to do is have the program print `1,2,3,4` and ignore the integers that have already been printed.

My usual approach to this would be to loop over the ArrayList with a for loop, but I am struggling with stopping the elements from repeating. I was thinking a counter system of some sort would probably work here but I am unsure on implementing it, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a set to avoid duplication?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: `HashSet` is a poor choice on its own, `LinkedHashSet` is better. At least if you plan to use `addAll()`.

Comment: `HashMap` would be a better choice for an operation like this.

Comment: Down-vote from me. No evidence of prior research - de-duplication is a very well understood problem in Java lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that easily with a `Set`, and no iteration.

- Use a `TreeSet` if you want to keep the natural order
- Use a `LinkedHashSet` if you want to keep the insertion order

**Example**

```
List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(2,1,3,3,4,1,2,5);
System.out.printf("Natural ordering: %s%n", new TreeSet<Integer>(numbers));
System.out.printf("Ordering based on insertion order: %s%n", new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(numbers));
```

**Output**

```
Natural ordering: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Ordering based on insertion order: [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: +1 Although, given that this behaviour would generalise to all lists, you could shorten your example to `List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(2,1,3,3,4,1,2,5);`.

Answer (score 6):

As you iterate and print, accumulate elements in a `HashSet`, testing the return value of `add`:

```
if (set.add(item)) printItem(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence is unimportant, covert the list into a set then print it. 
Otherwise for instance maintain a second list during traversal and add each element to it if it doesn't appeared before and print it, if it is in the checklist, skip it.

Comment: Have you heard about `LinkedHashSet`? I think that's what you wanted to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

First convert list to set and then print it. If order is not important, then you can use `HashSet`.

```
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(1);
  list.add(2);
  list.add(3);
    list.add(1);
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(list);
  for(Integer number : set){
      System.out.println(number);
  }
```

This will print only unique numbers.

Just replace with `TreeSet`to get ordered set.